# Deeper discussion for Angular, TypeScript, AngularJS, JavaScript (and maybe others) tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

There's been an increasingly unhelpful amount of Angular answers showing up for AngularJS questions, and visa versa (similarly with JavaScript and TypeScript). Many people at the company I work for (including myself) have resorted to using "-angularJS", "-JavaScript", or "-stackoverflow" in searches because so many questions that only relate to one of the technologies are tagged with both.

While I understand there are plenty of questions that do actually regard both technologies, this is the rare occurrence. For the case of Angular and AngularJS, there are over 3,000 questions tagged with both, yet it seems like 1-2 in 10 actually applies to or includes both.

What I am wondering is if it's possible to have a "needs review" check on tag combinations to help mitigate this kind of incorrect tagging? This could be applied for a good amount of misused tag combinations, but still allow the ones that actually need both though. Many of these tags directly say they shouldn't be used to refer to one or the other, but they still get included, throwing off search accuracy and helpfulness (and possibly spamming tag watchers with unrelated questions).

Here is a quick list of both tags as needed:

- [Checking the Angular/AngularJS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017699/how-can-i-check-which-version-of-angular-im-using)
- [Asking for equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463293/whats-the-equivalent-of-state-params-angular-1-ui-router-in-angular-2)
- [Tagging both JS and TS, but not specifying in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500679/how-can-i-compare-date-strings)
- [Specifies Angular and a specific version, as well as other relevant libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840152/angular-has-no-exported-member-observable)

And here is a quick list of what might be improper use of tag combinations:

- [No reference to AngularJS in the question, specifies Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349456/angular-5-check-if-a-field-exists-in-firebase)
- [Seems to just throw all the tags on there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932690/angular-6-compare-two-observables-lengths) - specifies Angular version in the code. With that, it's most likely TS as well.
- [Asks specifically for TS, but still tags JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575235/compare-dates-as-strings-in-typescript)
- [Seems specific to types and TS, but is also tagging JS and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691889/error-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature)

*Note:* There are plenty of other tags this applies to; this is just the area I am personally the most familiar with.

Comment: Many such combinations exist. [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave] are commonly combined by people asking Octave questions thinking they’ll get a larger audience, though the tag excerpts explicitly state not to. — It’ll be nice to have a system where such tag combinations are queued for review.

Comment: It would really help to just give like three examples here of content which is problematic in order to help clarify the problem you are observing for those of us not in the "people at the company you work for" group.

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ! I added some examples of what I believe are both good and bad usages of the tags (specific to my realm). Please let me know if I should add anything else.
@CrisLuengo - thanks for the feedback and more examples where this can be beneficial.

Comment: Isn't the answer to this to just correct the tagging as and when. Tags are always added incorrectly/mistagged in all technologies. The only solution is to fix what you find. I've lost count of the amount of [tag:java] tags I've had to remove on [tag:javascript] questions

Comment: @OneLunchMan thanks, but I would argue that if a **deeper** review is needed over such large collection of questions, then I'd like to have more than 3-4 bad examples. May you give 10 bad examples in need of retagging?

Comment: @Cœur I included a more general search to avoid a massive question of just examples. If a general consensus is that I add more, I easily can. "For the case of Angular and AngularJS, there are over 3,000 questions tagged with both, yet it seems like 1-2 in 10 actually applies to or includes both."

Comment: The naming AngularJS and Angular does not help and adds to confusion. Even when it was AngularJS people would, reasonably, just call it Angular. Now I tend to reference Angular 2, just to distinguish from the earlier version. For the novice it is even trickier to recognise the distinction, and so the doubling of tags is not going to go away. Who would have the time and commitment to keep modding this?

Comment: @TravisJ the problem is, at least in this instance, that the review queues are already overflowing with *-JS questions. I'm not sure adding another one would necessarily help?

Comment: It seems that the crux of this argument is that people don't know how to tag their questions.  This hasn't changed for almost ten years, and I'm not sure I see it changing anytime soon - especially with Angular.  Realistically speaking, I would believe the best thing we can do is interdict and fix the issue where and when it becomes an issue.

Comment: @JaredSmith - I believe you pinged the wrong user. But since you asked, is the current set of reviews really prohibitive to more? Unsure.

Comment: @TravisJ yes, meant that for someone else. That's what I get for using my phone instead of PC.

Comment: @AndyG "Who would have the time and commitment to keep modding this" well some do :) I agree with the original post, this is getting out of hand. I don't know if it's possible, but maybe prohibit the creation of a subject with the two tags ? The OP would have to ask for moderation on his post to add both tags. That would greatly reduce the amount of modding needed, because as said, questions regarding both tags are OVNIs.

Comment: I mean, when I search on Google, I frequently search using "angular -angularjs". I'm not sure why it would be any different on SO. On SO, at least, you can add the `angularjs` tag to your list of ignored tags and never see them... And as far as TypeScript goes, valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript, so I'm not sure why you'd want to rule JavaScript questions out.

Comment: Yeah, this is kindof a fuzzy mess and a hit or miss. With questions that are for "Angular" and have the "AngularJS" tag, the search excluding AngularJS ends up excluding possibly viable results just because of incorrect tagging. "Valid JS is valid TS", by this I assume you mean without the type checks in the way (referencing the ability to have the compiler ignore type errors)?

Comment: I think you're missing the underlying fact, it is certainly a very unpleasant one.  You are racking up technical debt by being stuck on such an ancient Angular version.  Taking a dependency on Google code is risky, you have to be just as "nimble" as they are to keep up.  Not nearly as free as it looks.

Comment: I myself don't know any of AngularJS nor TS but I already answered a bunch of these questions, because even though OP is writing in this flavor, the underlying APIs are still the same: javascript and DOM APIs (for in browser). [This example you gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575235/compare-dates-as-strings-in-typescript) is a good example of that, where TS or not, these are JS Date objects and how to compare it is known by [javascript] followers. Can't tell for Angular AngularJS though.

Comment: As far as Google searches go, I'm not sure it's specifically a SO problem - I find that I often have to specify "-angularjs" even for non-SO content, because apparently it doesn't distinguish between the two. And then of course there's W3Schools' "Angular" tutorials...

Comment: You're absolutely right @JohnMontgomery, there are many places that don't correctly distinguish between the two. That being said, I guess my question comes down to more of "what are SO's goals?" While I can sit here and draw conclusions on searches for this, I'm still pretty green to this community and would love to hear what others think!