# Are TypeScript questions, that are not related to types or configuration, just JavaScript questions?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many questions tagged as TypeScript questions, but in my opinion they are just JavaScript questions written with TypeScript ([this one for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336187/how-to-update-nested-object-in-typescript), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333900/how-to-eliminate-duplicate-object-from-a-list-of-arrays-of-objects)). What should I do in this case? Flag it as duplicate if I find the corresponding JavaScript question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to put a tag on a question that is barely related to a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376378) or [Should I remove the JavaScript tag when the question only has TypeScript?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384849)

Comment: Given that JS is a subset of TS, questions tagged with typescript can indeed be answered by JS answers, so if you find a fitting duplicate, vote!

Comment: @JonasWilms I think that you are contradicting your own argument: if TS has broader solutions than pure JS does, then dupeclosing would curtail non-JS solutions where they are implicitly desired. Now, if you can claim that if we strip all TS bits and are left with a javascript question, that would be totally different.

Comment: typescript has no non-js solutions.

Comment: @Braiam not "solutions" but "typesafety". `arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)` would be valid in both JS and TS (although you can tell the compiler to reject it). To turn it into a "real" typescript solution, you'd add types to get typesafety: `arr.sort((a: number, b: number) => a - b)`. Now adding these types is, in most cases, trivial and can be left to the OP. In cases were the typings get more complicated, there can be Typescript questions.

Answer (score 1):

YES! Questions containing TypeScript can, in a lot of cases, be answered by pure JavaScript answers.

Turning JavaScript into TypeScript can be done by adding types, or just typing anything as `any` (which TypeScript implicitly does, making JS a valid subset of TS). In most cases, adding typings is trivial, and the *actual problem* is caused by the way the JavaScript language works. Therefore answers do apply to TypeScript questions, and the OP should be able to adapt the solutions with proper types.

In cases were adding types is not trivial, I'd prefer answering the question with proper TypeScript types, referencing the original answer. Questions asking about *types*, or TypeScript only syntax (*enums*, *classes*), cannot be answered in JavaScript.

Comment: `class` is valid JavaScript ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I certainly know that, but classes in Typescript have a bit more syntactic sugar (e.g. `constructor(public prop: type)`)

Comment: Personally I consider Java Script without enough "type hints" to make it typesafe not to be valid Typescript, as it misses the point of a person using Typescript.

Comment: @ianRingrose totally agree, however for beginners it might be easier to go with `any` in more complex cases. Mapped types, conditional types, etc. are not that trivial.